Are there any game breaking consequences of allowing an Action to be used for an additional Bonus Action, with limits?
At my table, we are experimenting with a following houserule:

You can use your Action on your turn to take a Bonus Action instead. You cannot take the same Bonus Action twice in your turn, and you can't prepare bonus actions.

It seemed reasonable, if someone wants to do something that's exceptionally swift and low effort for them instead of full effort thing like casting a spell or attacking, it makes sense. And I see no ways my players could abuse that.
This would allow, for example, casting a Healing Word and using Shadar-Kai racial bonus action teleport, or moving Hunter's Mark and using one of the magic items that require bonus action. It would also make arguing if Moon Druids can still wildshape using normal Action moot.
Am I, as a DM, stepping on a mineturtle here? Any dangers to the game I don't see now? I don't mind my players getting a bit more powerful, I can scale encounters to accommodate that. What I don't want is trivializing encounters and some classes getting way more boost than others.
We are playing Turn of Fortune's Wheel so

 Each player has 3 different character classes. With 4 players it means 12 classes and I do not want one player to reap all the benefits with other left behind. On the other hand, they're dying quite a lot anyway so making them more powerful is a non-issue.

But the above spoiler should matter only a little if at all, I hope.
Highest voted answer to a similar question Which balancing issues, if any, would arise from allowing PCs to spend actions on bonus action features? points out the dangers of allowing the same bonus action twice, and the danger of readying a bonus actions, but these two we already eliminated.

This question is similar to: Which balancing issues, if any, would arise from allowing PCs to spend actions on bonus action features?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Wow that dupe flag comment text has gotten verbose--the linked question explicitly excluded feats, so I figure if it doesn't sufficiently answer your question you can probably rescope yours to get a useful answer for your case.

@KernelPanic I edited to point out that we have already eliminated dangers presented in the Q&A linked by you.

Is the point to allow the character to take 2 bonus actions?  As in, instead of taking an action, and then a bonus action, the character can take a bonus action and then another bonus action?  It might help if you stated the motivation -- "so the x character can do y", or something like that.

@Jack For example Healing Word and racial bonus action teleport.  Or moving Hunter's Mark and using one of the magic items that require bonus action.

Isn't this a duplicate of another question, where someone playtested this exact house rule, plus or minus some niche exceptions?

@Laurel what you linked is only about casting spells with bonus action requirement as an action. From the 3 examples I have given, only one includes casting a spell at all.

Do you think it would be a big deal if I read the spoiler also how do you do the thing where you can cover it up?

@Mołot It seems like the question and answer Laurel posted is NOT just about casting spells with bonus action requirements. The question begins with that as the jumping point, but nowhere does it state that they would ONLY be allowing spell bonus actions, and even imply that it would apply to features instead of spells, saying "however, I would not allow the same type of bonus action to be taken twice (so no giving bardic inspiration to two allies on the same turn, for instance)". Even the answer Laurel specifically linked doesn't say that was tested on spells only.

@ElvinaMoonlight  The spoiler might be significant if you're playing the Turn of Fortune's Wheel adventure, which is linked in the question.  Regarding how to make the spoiler, when you edit a question, right above where you edit the body of the question you'll see a ribbon of controls, and on the right, there's a question mark.  The question mark will give you markdown help.  Same thing for editing answers.

Not a duplicate.

@SeriousBri: It's a duplicate. The other question asks for any game-breaking issues, which is a superset of the game-breaking issues that this question asks about. Any answer to this question is a legitimate answer to the other question, and best answered at the duplicate, with this question being a breadcrumb on the way there. The narrowing in this question does not, in any way, alter the parameters of the original question, which fully encompasses what this question asks about. We don't need two questions with >95% overlap in their Venn Diagram circles.

@SeriousBri It appears to me almost the same question, as ShadowRanger said.

It's a different question insofar as it specifies limits. The problems enumerated in https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132767/which-balancing-issues-if-any-would-arise-from-allowing-pcs-to-spend-actions-o seem to be mostly resolved by the limitations here.

Yeah, this question specifically excludes the aspects called out in the last answer (readying a BA and using the same BA twice per turn), so the last answer fundamentally cannot apply to this question. +1 to the not a duplicate camp from me; this is almost like someone submitting a v2 homebrew after changing it based on feedback, albeit from two different users.

Perhaps ... I'd have a conversation with your players to determine which Bonus Action(s) they would regularly be using as an Action and have them mark them as an Action instead of a Bonus Action. That way, there won't be back and forth on "Did I just use that as my main Action or Bonus Action?".  Also, some random OP moment won't happen without your being prepared for it. Maybe run a couple of practice encounters to see how it flows.
While I can totally see how some Bonus Actions could be very useful as an Action instead, a lot are built to support the Actions. However, as long as you leave the line of communication open with the players, I'm sure you will figure out what works best for your group and campaign. Good luck!

Am I, as a DM, stepping on a mineturtle here?
Yes
House rules, by definition, mean your game is different than someone else's game. Having said that, I use them... but sparingly, as I want my players to have a predictable gaming environment, and any house rule, no matter how minor, requires them to know an exception at my table.
Players have plenty of official rules, along with exceptions to those rules to keep track of. Adding house rules means the players need to also keep track of what rules apply at your table. House rules can improve your game, but can also lead to players unwittingly losing track of what's official and what's a house rule.

This is answering an incredibly generic portion of the question, without addressing the specific proposal at all. Telling people house rules are potentially dangerous when they're asking about problems with a specific house rule reads as facetious.

@ShadowRanger - Yet, it's the most consequential portion of the question.

This answer would benefit from any reasons as to why this is actually an issue. "This houserule is risky because houserules are risky and this is a houserule" doesn't give OP anything actionable to work with.

@Shivers because your game is different and can also lead to players unwittingly losing track of what's official and what's a house rule... I am constantly correcting players who assume house rules they have encountered elsewhere are rules as written. That's it. No amount of blathering can change this.

Unless your ruleset allows more than 1 bonus action to be taken a turn, then no. You can only ever use 1 bonus action per turn, so being able to just waste an action to use a bonus action, which then you can't do anything else is just a waste of an action, as it does absolutely nothing.
So, no. There are no consequences, let alone game breaking to using this ruleset.

i am under the impression that your misread the question (understandable as its title is confusing)

I think you understood the question the other way around - Mołot worded the proposed rule as "You can use your Action on your turn to take a Bonus Action instead.", but your answer seems to talk about using a Bonus Action to take Actions.
edit: oops, Anne beat me to this comment, I'll leave it up though, as maybe it's a bit clearer

@HoneyBattery Ah, you're right. Reading it again, I see I was mistaken. But then the answer for this question would simply be that it doesn't change anything. You can only use a bonus action once a turn, you can use a bonus action every turn, so this ruleset provides no advantages whatsoever.

I feel as though you ought to delete that which you no longer agree with, especially if you misunderstood the question. Regarding the use of multiple bonus actions per turn, the post clearly indicates examples of multiple bonus actions being used, so I'm unclear on why you're assuming that the general rule is still in place.

@Pyrotechnical What else am I supposed to assume? No specific amount of bonus actions you could take per turn was specified, so should I not default to the base rules?

Besides allowing for 2 bonus actions, I'm unsure how else to interpret: "This would allow, for example, casting a Healing Word and using Shadar-Kai racial bonus action teleport, or moving Hunter's Mark and using one of the magic items that require bonus action."

@Pyrotechnical Yes - Healing word and the Shadar-Kai racial bonus are both bonus actions. Without the new ruleset, you can't cast these two in the same turn, however with the ruleset, you can cast one as an action instead. The ruleset does not change the amount of bonus actions you can use.

FWIW I think this answer would be a lot better if the word "absolutely" were removed. I would say "no material consequences" instead of "absolutely no consequences".
("Don't argue for a stronger claim than you need to," my dissertation advisor once told me.)

@quest1onable Given that the OP lists multiple examples of players being able to use two bonus actions within one turn using this houserule, I think it's pretty clear that the houserule includes the ability to use two bonus actions in a turn if your action is used for a bonus action. As you noted, the houserule does nothing (perhaps outside of some extreme edge cases) if that's not the case and OP would not have needed to explicitly disallow using the same BA twice if using two BAs in a turn was, at a baseline, not allowed under their houserule.

I think the 'if your read of a feature indicates that it can't do anything at all, then you've misread it' principle applies here. I wish it had a name.
