# Would there be any significant balance implications for letting a player forfeit their action to take a second bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, actions, bonus-action

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if there would be any significant balance implications for letting a player forfeit their action to take an additional bonus action (but not the other way around).

I know there would be balance implications for the other way around so that's why I said that.

I also know that RAW they're not at all interchangeable but as a house rule option maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Which balancing issues, if any, would arise from allowing PCs to spend actions on bonus action features?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132767/which-balancing-issues-if-any-would-arise-from-allowing-pcs-to-spend-actions-o). Also related: [What overpowered combinations would be available if I allow a bonus action to be used in place of a standard action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67558/what-overpowered-combinations-would-be-available-if-i-allow-a-bonus-action-to-be)

Comment: Oh my bad, I did this from mobile so it didn't suggest possible duplicates. Thanks

Comment: It’s all good! Duplicates just make the answers easier to find. Thanks for contributing a new wording. :)