# Why can't you use a bonus action in place of an action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions

It's pretty well established that you can't use a bonus action (spell or otherwise) as your action on your turn. See [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55899/48103) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111389/48103) for those questions. But I still don't really understand, *why* are the rules are set up that way?

The answers in the linked questions reference page 189 in the PHB where it says:

> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

Does anyone know why there isn't a caveat along the lines of "you can only take two bonus actions if you use one in place of your action"?

I wouldn't consider it productive to question why every rule is set up the way it is. But in this instance a quick search online will turn up numerous people who have a houserule that bonus actions can be used as actions, so apparently the reasoning behind it isn't clear for a lot of players. Something from an official source would obviously be best, but I'd take a tweet from one of the game designers or even specific game situations where this would be problematic too.

Comment: *Why did the designers write the game this way?* and similar questions are no longer fielded by the site (see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/8610)). However, the site can totally answer a question like *Would it be unbalanced if I made a house rule that allows a character to take an action as a bonus action?* or whatever the change is that you're considering.

Comment: These don't exactly answer your question, but here are some useful questions about houserules that change the rule in question: "[Which balancing issues, if any, would arise from allowing PCs to spend actions on bonus action features?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132767)" and "[What overpowered combinations would be available if I allow a bonus action to be used in place of a standard action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67558)"