# Can I make an attack as my action, and cast a spell with a casting time of 1 action as my bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, spellcasting, bonus-action

I am playing a rogue who chose the archetype Arcane Trickster, which means I can cast spells.

Can I make a normal-range or close-range attack for my main action, and as a bonus action cast a spell that requires 1 action (e.g. *chill touch* or *fire bolt*)?

Comment: And with that out of the way, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for think it might work or might not work? Having that would greatly help answerers clarify any underlying uncertainties or misunderstandings.

Comment: Does this answer you question?  [Are actions and bonus actions interchangeable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111389/14878)

Comment: Related but asking the other way around (using a an action to cast a "bonus action" spell): [Can I use a spell with a casting time of “Bonus Action” as my action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55899/14878)

Comment: Related (but different, I think): "[Are actions and bonus actions interchangeable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111389)" and "[Can I use a spell with a casting time of "Bonus Action" as my action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55899)" and "[Which balancing issues, if any, would arise from allowing PCs to spend actions on bonus action features?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132767)" and "[What overpowered combinations would be available if I allow a bonus action to be used in place of a standard action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67558)"

Comment: In this case, I don't think it matters about direction as it's still the same question; can you substitute actions and bonus actions for each other? That's what the referenced question is asking. Otherwise it opens up the possibility of all the permutations of what a character can do as separate questions.

Comment: @MivaScott Assuming this is reference to the exchange above (now gone) there was originally a different question linked which got edited out. As for specific/permutations, that's why I want clarification from the querent. If there is a feature, rule, etc. which is causing this, there is a specific clarification to make there, one way or the other.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking if you can just always do action-only things as a bonus action somehow? (If so, why do you think you would be able to do that?) Or are you asking if the 'can only cast a cantrip with 1-action casting time' bonus-action-casting rule prevents you from taking other actions besides casting levelled spells?  (If so, why do you think it would prevent taking the Attack action?)

Answer (score 18):

### tl;dr - no

You cannot use your bonus action to cast a spell - unless it is explicitly stated that *the spell's casting time is one bonus action*.

On any given turn, you may take one Action and One Bonus action. An action can be one of various things, but is usually either attacking with a weapon or casting a spell.

A bonus action is very different to a normal action. You can only use a bonus action if you have a feature, spell, magical item, etc. that requires a bonus action to use. For example, as a rogue, your 'cunning action' feat which you get at 2nd level allows you to use your bonus action to use the dash, disengage or Hide actions (which normally take a full action to perform).

Comment: Relevant for Arcane Trickster: you can use your Bonus Action to *use* an existing Mage Hand, but not to *cast* Mage Hand if you don't already have it active.  It's still 1 Action to task, and your class feature only affects the "on subsequent turns" Action the spell description lets you take.

Answer (score 11):

A spell with a casting time of one action can only be cast as an action, not as a bonus action.

See the basic rules for [casting time](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingTime):

> Most spells require a single action to cast, but some spells require a bonus action, a reaction, or much more time to cast.

A spell specifies if it has a casting time of one **action** or one **bonus action**.

And the basic rules for [bonus actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions):

> You can take a bonus action only when a special ability, spell, or other feature of the game states that you can do something as a bonus action. You otherwise don't have a bonus action to take.

You can only use a spell as a bonus action if it has a casting time of one bonus action.

Answer (score 2):

#### Only if you take three levels in Sorcerer and choose the *Quickened Spell* metamagic or six levels in Cleric and follow the Order Domain

As the other answers correctly note, in general this cannot be done. Actions are actions, and bonus actions are bonus actions. You can only take a bonus action if a spell, feat, feature, or similar explicitly says you can-- otherwise, you don't have a bonus action to use.

There are a couple of exceptions, in this case the *PHB* Sorcerer class and the Order Domain Cleric (*Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*) (h/t to Medix2 for the Order Cleric example).

Sorcerers have a special resource called *sorcery points*, and at level 3, sorcerers can take two metamagic options. One of these, *Quickened Spell*, allows the sorcerer to spend two sorcery points to cast a spell that normally requires an action to cast and instead lets them cast it as a bonus action.

The Order Cleric gains a feature at level 6, *Embodiment of the Law*, which allows them to cast an enchantment spell of first level or higher, and which normally has a casting time of one action, as a bonus action instead.